# Como cambiar las leyendas o nombres en eje x de boxplot pandas

Tags: pandas

Tengo creado un dataframe con columnas de temperaturas por mes.

Cuando hago boxplot con pandas, en el eje x me aparece el nombre que le puse a las columnas, pero quiero cambiarlos en la figura.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = matriz, columns=['T Enero','T Febrero','T Marzo','T Abril','T Mayo','T Junio','T Julio','T Agosto','T Septiembre','T Octubre','T Noviembre','T Diciembre'])

#Boxplot Temperaturas de Tropopausa     
plt.figure(figsize=(14,11))
plt.xlabel('Box plot por Mes',fontsize=15) 
plt.ylabel('Temperatura (K)',fontsize=15)
plt.title(('Temperaturas de Tropopausa en Córdoba').decode('utf8'))   #decode para que no den error los tildes
boxplot=df.boxplot(column=['T Enero','T Febrero','T Marzo','T Abril','T Mayo','T Junio','T Julio','T Agosto','T Septiembre','T Octubre','T Noviembre','T Diciembre'],rot=45,fontsize='medium')
plt.savefig(rutasalfig+'tempTrop.png',dpi=200)
```

**Box plot**

> [image: Box plot]

Quiero cambiar las etiquetas del eje x y ponerles lo que quiera.

Probe con:

```
labels = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
boxplot=df.boxplot(column=['T Enero','T Febrero','T Marzo','T Abril','T Mayo','T Junio','T Julio','T Agosto','T Septiembre','T Octubre','T Noviembre','T Diciembre'],rot=45,fontsize='medium',**labels=labels**)
```

y no funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución

Agregué la linea

plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],fontsize=15)

Y funcionó

El código quedó así:

plt.figure(figsize=(14,11))

boxplot=df.boxplot(column=['T Enero','T Febrero','T Marzo','T Abril','T Mayo','T Junio','T Julio','T Agosto','T Septiembre','T Octubre','T Noviembre','T Diciembre'],rot=45)

plt.xlabel('Box plot por Mes',fontsize=15)

plt.ylabel('Temperatura (K)',fontsize=15)

plt.title(('Temperaturas de Tropopausa en Córdoba').decode('utf8'),fontsize=20)   #decode para que no den error los tildes

plt.xticks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],fontsize=15)

plt.savefig(rutasalfig+lugar+'tempTrop.png',dpi=200)